# Construct a 'long long'

Tags: gcc

How do you construct a `long long` in gcc, similar to constructing an `int` via `int()`

The following fails in gcc (4.6.3 20120306) (but passes on MSVC for example).

```
myFunctionCall(someValue, long long());
```

with error `expected primary-expression before 'long'` (the column position indicates the first long is the location).

A simple change

```
myFunctionCall(someValue, (long long)int());
```

works fine - that is construct an `int` and cast to `long long` - indicating that gcc doesn't like the `long long` ctor.

## Summary Solution

To summarize the brilliant explanation below from @birryree:

- many compilers don't support `long long()` and it may not be standards compliant
- constructing `long long` is equivalent to the literal `0LL`, so use `myFunctionCall(someValue, 0LL)`
- alternatively use a `typedef long_long_t long long` then `long_long_t()`
- lastly, consider using `uint64_t` *if* you are after a type that is exactly 64 bits on any platform, rather than a type that is at *least* 64 bits, but may vary on different platforms.

Comment: You could use `int64_t()` instead of `long long()` - it's a `typedef` of `long long` and gives more clarity that it's a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Can we guarantee int64_t always has the same number of bits as long long?

Comment: `int64_t` guarantees 64-bits, whereas `long long` is at least 64-bits. The other way you can create an int as a certain type is to specify the type suffix, like `0LL`.

Comment: _strictly_ speaking none are the same as default constructing a long long, but both int64_t and the `0LL` are pretty good workarounds - more than enough to at least get me compiling.

Comment: Default constructing an integral type gives you back a `0` as a value. However, it's not really a constructor in the sense that classes have constructors - the `()` look like constructors, but using `int()` is the same as just saying `int x = 0`. It's one of those weird things in C++ that is there for template support. Do note that in `cstdint`/`stdint.h`, `int64_t` is a `typedef long long`, but if you really need your own to ensure it, you can make your own typedef like `typedef long long MyLongLong` and do this `MyLongLong()`.

Comment: I don't think default ctor returns zero always - more typical behaviour is to leave memory untouched. Again, some nice workarounds but it still should be possible to construct a POD with resorting to my own typedefs... I wonder if this is a gcc bug or you just need some slightly different syntax?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11077/discussion-between-zero-and-birryree)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I wanted a definitive answer on what the expected behavior was, so I [posted a question on `comp.lang.c++.moderated`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/Rkz8mbjrJ_Y) and got some great answers in return.** *So a thank you goes out to Johannes Schaub, Alf P. Steinbach (both from SO), and Francis Glassborrow for some information*

This is not a bug in GCC - in fact it will break across multiple compilers - GCC 4.6, GCC 4.7, and Clang complain about similar errors like `primary expression expected before '('` if you try this syntax:

```
long long x = long long();
```

Some primitives have spaces, and that is not allowed if you want to use the constructor-style initialization because of binding (`long()` is bound, but `long long()` has a free `long`). Types with spaces in them (like `long long`) can not use the `type()`-construction form.

MSVC is more permissive here, though technically non-standard compliant (and it's not a language extension that you can disable).

#### Solutions/Workarounds

There are alternatives for what you want to do:

- Use `0LL` as your value in place of attempting `long long()` - they would produce the same value.

  This is how most code will be written too, so it will be most understandable to anyone else reading your code.
- From your comments it seems like you really want `long long`, so you can `typedef` yourself to always guarantee you have a `long long` type, like this:

  ```
  int main() {
      typedef long long MyLongLong;
      long long x = MyLongLong(); // or MyLongLong x = MyLongLong();
  }
  ```
- Use a template to get around needing explicit naming:

  ```
  template<typename TypeT>
  struct Type { typedef TypeT T(); };

  // call it like this:
  long long ll = Type<long long>::T();
  ```
- As I mentioned in my comments, you can use an aliased type, like `int64_t` (from `<cstdint>`), which across common platforms is a `typedef long long int64_t`. This is a more platform dependent than the previous items in this list.

  `int64_t` is a fixed-width type that is 64-bits, which is typically how wide `long long` is on platforms like linux-x86 and windows-x86. `long long` is at least 64-bit wide, but can be longer. If your code will only run on certain platforms, or if you really need a fixed-width type, this might be a viable choice.

#### C++11 Solutions

Thanks to the C++ newsgroup, I learned some additional ways of doing what you want to do, but unfortunately they're only in the realm of C++11 (and MSVC10 doesn't support either, and only very new compilers either way would):

- The `{}` way:

  ```
  long long ll{}; // does the zero initialization
  ```
- Using what Johannes refers to as the 'bord tools' in C++11 with `std::common_type<T>`

  ```
  #include <type_traits>

  int main() {
      long long ll = std::common_type<long long>::type();
  }
  ```

---

#### So is there a real difference between `()` and initializing with `0` for POD types?

You say this in a comment:

> I don't think default ctor returns zero always - more typical behaviour is to leave memory untouched.

Well, for primitive types, that is not true at all.

From **Section 8.5** of the *ISO C++ Standard/2003* (don't have 2011, sorry, but this information didn't change too much):

> To default-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> — if `T` is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>
> — if `T` is an array type, each element is
>   default-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

The last clause is most important here because `long long`, `unsigned long`, `int`, `float`, etc. are all scalar/POD types, and so calling things like this:

```
int x = int();
```

Is exactly the same as doing this:

```
int x = 0;
```

---

#### Generated code example

Here is a more concrete example of what actually happens in code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void create_and_print() {
   T y = T();
   std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   create_and_print<unsigned long long>();

   typedef long long mll;
   long long y = mll();
   long long z = 0LL;

   int mi = int();
}
```

Compile this with:

```
g++ -fdump-tree-original construction.cxx
```

And I get this in the generated tree dump:

```
;; Function int main() (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original

{
  typedef mll mll;
  long long int y = 0;
  long long int z = 0;
  int mi = 0;

  <<cleanup_point <<< Unknown tree: expr_stmt
  create_and_print<long long unsigned int> () >>>>>;
  <<cleanup_point   long long int y = 0;>>;
  <<cleanup_point   long long int z = 0;>>;
  <<cleanup_point   int mi = 0;>>;
}
return <retval> = 0;



;; Function void create_and_print() [with T = long long unsigned int] (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original

{
  long long unsigned int y = 0;

  <<cleanup_point   long long unsigned int y = 0;>>;
  <<cleanup_point <<< Unknown tree: expr_stmt
  (void) std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< ((struct __ostream_type *) std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< (&cout, y), endl) >>>>>;
}
```

---

#### Generated Code Implications

So from the code tree generated above, notice that all my variables are just being initialized with `0`, even if I use constructor-style default initialization, like with `int mi = int()`. GCC will generate code that just does `int mi = 0`.

My template function that just attempts to do default construction of some passed in `typename T`, where `T = unsigned long long`, also produced just a `0`-initialization code.

---

#### Conclusion

So in conclusion, if you want to default construct primitive types/PODs, it's like using `0`.

Comment: I'd give a +1 if the answer weren't so casual about "long long" and "uint64_t" being "usually the same" that it actually lists this as the first "solution". For decades now we tried to educate programmers *not* to make assumptions about the width of int, long, or long long, which is why `<stdint.h>` was *invented*...

Comment: @DevSolar - I didn't intend to give the list any ordered weight, but I could see how it could be interpreted that way. I'll edit it to emphasize common solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort - thanks for all the detail! (And now it's obvious that `int i;` and `int i = int()` are _not_ the same... how silly of me!). Also, good edit re: uint64_t, I think it's important to make that clear. Maybe in 30 years using `<stdint.h>` will be the norm...